# remote server to deploy a node website who display nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a probleme to deploy my web site with node on a renote host
the first script server.js displays the server connexion
But my midelware mw.js seems to not work
Nothing is display
No error message in the logs
Maybe a trouble to display ma index.ejs?

Thanks for your help

My node app works fine in local
my Main files server.js

```js
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var express = require('express')

var middelware = require('./routes/mw')
var http = require('http')
var path = require('path');
//var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");


//console.log(session);
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascript')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/image')));
app.use('/',middelware );

app.listen(3000)
console.log('3000 is the magic port');
```

mw.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
/* GET pages listing. */
router.get('/:nom/', function(req, res, next) {
    
  let pages=['accueil','article','contact'];
  var bool=false;
  pages.forEach(function(nomPage) {
  if(nomPage==req.params.nom){
  bool=true;
  console.log(nomPage);
  nomP=req.params.nom;
  // requete mysql 
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port:3306,
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "pageWeb"
  }); 
  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    
   // Select where 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE nomP = '"+nomP+"'", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    ctnpage=result[0].contenuP;
    console.log(ctnpage);
    // affichage via ejs dans la page 
    res.render('index', {
        contenuP:ctnpage ,
        nomP:pages
    });
  });
 
});
```

What can I do?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You've got to install express on your remote. Not sure why you can't play around with node modules - how do you actually deploy your application then?

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I deploy only with package.json "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
I go to ask to install express to the host

Comment: Okay, but physically - how - via ssh, some IDE, FTP? You log onto the machine?

Comment: By sftp :) with filezilla :) for node I have the logs on the remote server where is the error message

Comment: So, AFAIK, in such case you have to upload dependencies yourself (the `node_modules` directory from within your project's root), too. Keep in mind, however, that server machine might be different from your local PC, so generally it'd be better to install them on the machine directly. But you could try, I guess - prior to playing with it, though, make some back up copy. **Edit** - of course, if SFTP is enabled, you can certainly connect to the remote machine via `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks so much I had a big doubt about node modules I do that If I have a problem I come back thanks :)

Comment: Re hi 
The probleme with express is solved but nothing is display 
Of course the path are not the same I suppose
The ejs file seems to be not display 
Thanks for your Help
PS My page http://www.olopherne.online/accueil/
the text is from de host